# Processing two files using awk

Tags: text-processing, awk

I read [Comparing two files using Unix and Awk](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/84752/comparing-two-files-using-unix-and-awk). It is really interesting. I read and tested it, but I can't understand it completely and use it in other cases.

I have two files. `file1` has one field and the other one has 16 fields. I want to read elements of `file`1 and compare them with 3rd field of `file2`. If there was a match for each element, I sum value of field 5 in `file2`. As an example:

#### file 1

```
1
2
3
```

#### file 2

```
2 2 2 1 2
3 6 1 2 4 
4 1 1 2 3
6 3 3 3 4
```

For element 1 in `file1` I want to add values in field 5 of `file2` where value of field 3 is 1. And do the same for element 2 and 3 in `file1`. The output for 1 is (3+4=7) and for 2 is 2 and for 3 is 4.

I don't know how I should write it with awk.

Answer (score 22):

Here's one way. I have written it as an awk script so I can add comments:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/awk -f

{
    ## FNR is the line number of the current file, NR is the number of 
    ## lines that have been processed. If you only give one file to
    ## awk, FNR will always equal NR. If you give more than one file,
    ## FNR will go back to 1 when the next file is reached but NR
    ## will continue incrementing. Therefore, NR == FNR only while
    ## the first file is being processed.
    if(NR == FNR){
      ## If this is the first file, save the values of $1
      ## in the array n.
      n[$1] = 0
    }
    ## If we have moved on to the 2nd file
    else{
      ## If the 3rd field of the second file exists in
      ## the first file.
      if($3 in n){
        ## Add the value of the 5th field to the corresponding value
        ## of the n array.
        n[$3]+=$5
      }
    }
}
## The END{} block is executed after all files have been processed.
## This is useful since you may have more than one line whose 3rd
## field was specified in the first file so you don't want to print
## as you process the files.
END{
    ## For each element in the n array
    for (i in n){
    ## print the element itself and then its value
    print i,":",n[i];
    }
}
```

You can save that as a file, make it executable and run it like so:

```
$ chmod a+x foo.awk
$ ./foo.awk file1 file2
1 : 7
2 : 2
3 : 4
```

Or, you can condense it into a one-liner:

```
awk '
     (NR == FNR){n[$1] = 0; next}
     {if($3 in n){n[$3]+=$5}}
     END{for (i in n){print i,":",n[i]} }' file1 file2
```

Answer (score 9):

```
awk '
  NR == FNR {n[$3] += $5; next}
  {print $1 ": " n[$1]}' file2 file1
```

Comment: It does some extra work by summing non matched fields.

Comment: @Emmanuel, that's still one awk instructions per line of file2, which makes it shorter and faster than terdon's

Comment: brillant solution !