# AWK script to compare content of 2 files

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have 2 files ..

file1:

```
abc|123|check
def|456|map
ijk|789|globe
lmn|101112|equator
```

file2:

```
check
map
equator
globe
```

AWK function should compare 3rd column (after cut 3rd column & sort) of file1 comparing with file2 sorted content

- should return 1 if ALL lines are matching
- else should return 2

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this site is not a script writing service and you should at least attempt to do your own homework.

Comment: I tried my level best to use diff command, comm utility and tried to use uniq/sort ... but not able to join all those in two a single liner .. that was the reason to ask help for command .. if I get the idea, I can script it ... Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the response ...

comm -13 <(cut -d'|' -f3 file1 | sort | uniq) <(cat file2 | sort | uniq)

When I am running this command, getting the following error 

ksh: 0403-057 Syntax error: `(' is not expected.

TIA

Comment: @jordanm the OP is not asking you to write a script. He/she is asking about how to use a specific command in a specific way. That falls within the boundaries of questions here, AFAIK. A rudimentary question that falls within the guidelines for asking questions is nonetheless a legitimate question.

Answer (score 1):

```
function are_all_there {
    local num_diff=$(comm -3 <(cut -d'|' -f3 "$1" | sort) <(sort "$2") | wc -l)
    (( num_diff == 0 )) && return 1 || return 2
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments, it seems that `awk` is not your only option. so here is a non-awk method.
You don't mention the need for *unique* comparison in the question, but you have used `uniq` in the example in your comment. If you don't need a *unique* match, just remove sort's `-u` option. (tested in `bash`)
.

```
(($(comm -3 <( cut -d'|' -f3 file1 | sort -u ) \
            <( sort -u file2 ) | wc -l))) && echo 2 - not all match ||
                                             echo 1 - all match
```

Or, using `awk` for the final comparison - with a bit of help from `paste`.

```
paste <( cut -d'|' -f3 file1 | sort -u ) \
      <( sort -u file2 ) |
   awk '$1!=$2{m=2; exit} 
     END{ if(m == 2){print "2 - not all match"; exit;} 
                     print "1 - all match";}'
```

Or, `awk` [comparing two input files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/106645/2343)

```
 awk '{if(NR == FNR){a[NR]=$1}
       else{ if($1 != a[NR]){m=2; exit}}}  
      END{ if(m == 2){print "2 - not all match"; exit;} 
                      print "1 - all match";}' \
    <( cut -d'|' -f3 file1 | sort -u ) \
    <( sort -u file2 ) |
```

Answer (score 0):

Amusing CS answers! We do not actually have to sort anything, because this is a pure set comparison.

The input files are representation of a set in which the elements are  pairs. For instance if the line `foo` occurs 3 times in `file1`, that represents the element <`foo`, 3>. If `file2` contains `foo` 3 times, that means both sets contain this element. If `file2` doesn't contain `foo` or contains a different number of repetitions of `foo`, then it represents a set which does not contain <`foo`, 3>.

Furthermore, note that a set of pairs like <`foo`, 3> can be represented by a hash which maps the key `foo` to 3.

TXR Lisp awk macro:

```
(awk (:begin (set fs "|"))
     (:let (h1 (hash :equal-based)) (h2 (hash :equal-based)))
     ((= arg 1) (inc [h1 [f 2] 0]))
     ((= arg 2) (inc [h2 rec 0]))
     (:end (exit (equal h1 h2))))
```

This produces a successful termination status if the files are equal in the required way, otherwise a failed status:

```
$ txr comp.tl file1 file2
$ echo $?
0
$ echo map >> file2
$ txr comp.tl file1 file2
$ echo $?
1
```

If we want to complicate things for the calling program by making it parse "1" or "2" output, that can be done by changing the `:end` rule:

```
(:end (prn (if (equal h1 h2) "1" "2")))
```

Here is how things look in regular awk. The main difference is that we have terse syntax in which we don't have to define any variable that we reference; on the other hand, we have to write a pair of loops to compare two associative arrays, and generate our own `arg` variable to track which file we are processing. (GNU Awk has the `ARGIND` for this purpose.)

```
BEGIN { FS = "|" }
FNR == 1 { arg++ }
arg == 1 { h1[$3]++; }
arg == 2 { h2[$0]++; }
END { same = 1
      for (i in h1)
        if (h1[i] != h2[i]) {
          same = 0
          break
        }
      if (same)
        for (i in h2)
          if (h2[i] != h1[i]) {
            same = 0
            break
          }
      print same ? "1" : "2"; }
```