# Pattern Matching and Delete the whole line

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk, python, perl

I want to delete all the Lines of File 1, if Column1 of File1 matches exactly with Column 1 File2.

File 1:

```
r001:21:10    21    AAAAAATTTGC    *     =    XM:21
r002:21:10    21    YAAAATTTGC     *     =    nM:21
r001:21:10    21    TTAAAATTTGC    *     =    XM:21
r0012:21:10   21    LLAAAATTTGC    *     +    XM:21
r001:21:10    21    AAAAAATTTGC    *     =    GM:21
```

File2:

```
r001:21:10
r001:21:20
r002:41:36
r002:41:99
r002:41:87
r0012:21:1
```

Expected Output:

```
r002:21:10    21    YAAAATTTGC     *     =    nM:21
r0012:21:10   21    LLAAAATTTGC    *     +    XM:21
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use this `awk`:

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR {a[$i]; next}; !($1 in a)' f2 f1
r002:21:10    21    YAAAATTTGC     *     =    nM:21
r0012:21:10   21    LLAAAATTTGC    *     +    XM:21
```

#### Explanation

- `FNR==NR {a[$i]; next}` it reads the first file and saves the contents into the `a` array.
- `!($1 in a)` while reading the second file, it checks if the first field is in the `a` array. If not, prints the line.

Comment: @Stephane Chazelas, I don't see need of that semicolon. Why should it be there?

Comment: It's [required by POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html#tag_20_06_13_16), so you could expect some `awk` implementations to fail without it.

Comment: Having said that, I don't know of any `awk` implementation that does. I [once raised it to the autin group](http://austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=226)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I was revisiting the link you gave and apparently your proposal has been approved.

Comment: @fedorqui, some of it has been approve but not the part about needing `;` or newline between condition+action pairs. _The standard does not require support for `awk '/x/{print} {print}'` and this is intentional._ (actually the gawk maintainer objected to it).

Answer (score 2):

You could also do

```
$ grep -wvFf file2 file1
r002:21:10    21    YAAAATTTGC     *     =    nM:21
r0012:21:10   21    LLAAAATTTGC    *     +    XM:21
```

From `man grep`:

```
   -F, --fixed-strings
          Interpret PATTERN as a  list  of  fixed  strings,  separated  by
          newlines,  any  of  which is to be matched. 
   -f FILE, --file=FILE
          Obtain  patterns  from  FILE,  one  per  line.  
   -v, --invert-match
          Invert the sense of matching, to select non-matching lines. 
   -w, --word-regexp
          Select  only  those  lines  containing  matches  that form whole
          words.  The test is that the matching substring must  either  be
          at  the  beginning  of  the  line,  or  preceded  by  a non-word
          constituent character.
```

**NOTE**: This however, will search the entirety of each line of `file1`, not just the first column.

Comment: +1 from me. works fast and efficient also for large flat file databases.

Answer (score 2):

If the output order is not important and your shell supports [process substitution](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/shell-process-redirection) (bash does), you could use `join` on the `sorted` files:

```
join -v 1 <(sort -k1,1 file1) <(sort -k1,1 file2) | column -t
r0012:21:10  21  LLAAAATTTGC  *  +  XM:21
r002:21:10   21  YAAAATTTGC   *  =  nM:21
```

Explanation: `join` files on the first column, `-v 1` = output non-matching lines from first file. Files are `sorted` by their first column `-k1,1`. The last `column -t` does pretty printing.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like from another thread, I was able to find the answer using that method,

[Comparing two files using Unix and Awk](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/84752/comparing-two-files-using-unix-and-awk)

```
FNR == NR {
  f1[$1,$2,$3] = $0
  f1_c14[$1,$2,$3] = 1
  f1_c5[$1,$2,$3] = $4
  next
}

f1_c14[$1,$2,$3] {
  if ($4 != f1_c5[$1,$2,$3]) print f1[$1,$2,$3] ;
}

f1[$1,$2,$3] {
  if ($4 != f1_c5[$1,$2,$3]) print $0;
}
```

Comment: When copying, do so carefully please - you missed a closing brace. It also doesn't produce the required output (copying blindly doesn't really help that much).

Comment: I didn't copy it blindly. I spent time to understand how to use the arrays. It's awesome ! worked for me now.

Comment: If you present a piece of code as a solution, it should work on the data provided in the question you are answering - it doesn't seem to do so in this case.

Comment: Sorry ! I had been out for a while. I tested today using the test files, file1 and file2, just exactly as I posted here, and it returned the result as expected. Don't know why it doesn't work for you ? can you provide details of your steps ?

Comment: Use the data provided in **this** question not in the one from which you copied the script. Note, that the requirement here is different than in the other question (different fields to compare), although the person asking is the same - that should also make it clear, that this question is different. Then put first data set into `file1`, second data set into `file2` and script into `F`. Run `awk -f F -- file1 file2`. Understand what the script actually tries to do and you'll find out, that it, among other things, compares 1st, 2nd and 4th fields not just the 1st one.

Comment: Yes, I was using the two files that I posted here, not from the link that I used as a reference nor the one from this owner's thread. Just run awk -f test.awk file1 file2 (test.awk is the file that has my script). And it returned exactly each pair of lines that matched the first 3 fields as well as the fourth fields that didn't match.

Comment: Good. Now please compare this with the question you are trying to answer: *I want to delete all the Lines of File 1, if Column1 of File1 matches exactly with Column 1 File2.*

Comment: Not sure what are you trying to prove here rather then focusing on the solution. I did say "..delete or won't print out that line..". Hope that we can end it here.